# Page referrer for a specified page

Tags: google-analytics

My question is simple, on Google Analytics I want to report all the pages of my website that calls error/index.

For example, I want to see the evolution day by day of the number error/index and see what pages cause errors.

Comment: could you please clarify what do you mean by "calls error/index" and how your analytics tracking is set?

Comment: error/index is the name of the page

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : 
You go to Behaviour -> Site Content -> All pages and you choose "landing page" in the behaviour section in the "Secondary dimension" selection

So, You can see the pages throught which the visitors entered the selected page with the number of occurences